# Why the TS type of HTMLInputElement.files property may be null?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, dom

There is `input` with `type='file'` attribute like this:

```
function TestComp() {
  const onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const [file] = e.target.files;
    //...
  };

  return <input type='file' onChange={onChange}/>
}
```

Got error:

> type 'FileList | null' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)

The `e.target.files` TS type is:

```
interface HTMLInputElement extends HTMLElement { 
  /**
   * Returns a FileList object on a file type input object.
   */
  files: FileList | null;
}
```

In what scenario, the `e.target.files` may be `null`?

Comment: Because input has many types radio, text, number, file etc. Not all of them has the `files` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the behaviour of `HTMLFileElement`, it returns `null` for `files` if the `type` is not set to `file`.

```
const fileInput  = document.createElement('input');
fileInput.files // null 

fileInput.type = "file"
fileInput.files // FileList
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to work around with this a bit different way and it works

```
import React from 'react';

interface Event<T = EventTarget> {
    target: T;
}

export default function FileUploadPage() {

    const changeHandler = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
        const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
        const files = target.files;
        console.log(files)
    };

    const handleSubmission = () => {
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="file" name="file" multiple  onChange={changeHandler} />
            <div>
                <button onClick={handleSubmission}>Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```